# AS3 : if textfield.text is a string, why string functions does not work on it?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have a declaration:

```
private var textField:TextField = new TextField(220, 35, "Tap to flip the text!", "Roboto", 22, 0xf1f1f1, false);
```

and then I have command:

```
textField.text.split("").reverse().join("");
```

which I found here: http://curtismorley.com/2007/10/18/as3-quicktip-reversing-a-string-with-one-line-of-code/

Can someone explain to me why this command doesn't reverse this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does reverse the string. You don't see it though because you're not assigning the new value back to the textField.

```
textField.text = textField.text.split("").reverse().join("");
```

anything except an `=` after the text property will just be reading the value, not assigning it.

Also, your code isn't a valid textField, are you using some other extension of it?

Comment: Once more you save me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private var textField:TextField = new TextField(220, 35, "Tap to flip the text!", "Roboto", 22, 0xf1f1f1, false);
```

Where did you take that declaration from? It should have thrown you an error immediately.

> TextField     ()  Constructor public function TextField()
>
> Language Version:     ActionScript 3.0 Runtime Versions:  AIR 1.0, Flash
>   Player 9, Flash Lite 4
>
> Creates a new TextField instance. After you create the TextField
>   instance, call the addChild() or addChildAt() method of the parent
>   DisplayObjectContainer object to add the TextField instance to the
>   display list.
>
> The default size for a text field is 100 x 100 pixels.

Once  you fix that, it will work just fine.

Comment: sorry, I've wrote just this. there's a lot of code in between.